# не складываются значения checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function onclickCheckbox(cb1,cbv1) {
  var cb = document.getElementsByName('check1')[cb1];
  if (cb.checked) {
    var cbv=cbv+parseInt(document.getElementsByName('check1')[cb1].value);
    document.getElementsByName('chires')[cbv1].value=cbv;

}};
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name="check1" class="liver_1" value="5"onclick="onclickCheckbox(0,0)">
<label for="liver_1" class="liver_1">если у вас болит печень 1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" class="liver_1" value="3" onclick="onclickCheckbox(1,0)">
<label for="liver_1" class="liver_1">если у вас болит печень 1</label><br>
<input type="text" name="chires" value="0" size="5">
Нарушение порядка 'чи' печени(застой 'чи').
<br>
```

Comment: у вас input`ы имеют одинаковые имена...

Comment: Для `checkbox` это нормально

Answer (score 2):

Не складывается из-за ошибки в коде. Переменная `cbv` не определена на момент использования.

Также есть логическая ошибка - после снятия галочки значение не вычитается

Должно быть как-то так:

```js
function onclickCheckbox(cb1,cbv1) {
  var cb = document.getElementsByName('check1')[cb1];
  var sum_node = document.getElementsByName('chires')[cbv1];
  var current = parseInt( sum_node.value );

  if(cb.checked) {
    var cbv=current+parseInt(cb.value);
  } else {
    var cbv=current-parseInt(cb.value);
  }
  sum_node.value=cbv;
};
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" name="check1" class="liver_1" value="5"onclick="onclickCheckbox(0,0)">
<label for="liver_1" class="liver_1">если у вас болит печень 1</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" class="liver_1" value="3" onclick="onclickCheckbox(1,0)">
<label for="liver_1" class="liver_1">если у вас болит печень 1</label><br>
<input type="text" name="chires" value="0" size="5">
Нарушение порядка 'чи' печени(застой 'чи').
<br>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var summ = 0;

for (var i = 0; i<document.getElementsByTagName ("input").length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByTagName ("input")[i].type == "checkbox") {
        var num = parseInt (document.getElementsByTagName ("input")[i].value)
        summ += num;

        if (i==document.getElementsByTagName ("input").length-1) {
            alert (summ);
        };
  };
};
```

Получение суммы текстбоксов. Без всяких имён :)

Comment: А если есть несколько независимых наборов чекбоксов?

Comment: @Arnial такого условия автор не делал. Можно в первое if вставить проверку на id или name.